# Need Calculated formula for getting email id in Sharepoint 2007 List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007

I have a SharePoint 2007 list, I want to Auto-populate the Email id based on the Account Name(Person/Group type column).

**Eg:** if the persons account name is provided in the Account name column then his/her email id should get auto-populated in the Email id column of the same List.

Please provide a calculated formula for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's no supported to achieve it using Calculated column by default.

I suggest you use designer workflow. You can set the Email ID column value based on Account name column value in designer workflow.

Comment: Can you please provide code for fetching the Email from the people picker Using Sharepoint Designer.